# What would cause Visual Studio to use an old web.config?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, iis

I have an MVC project using a `web.config`with a connection string that I've updated - however my application continues to use an old connection string, even after restarting VS and searching my solution for the old value that's being used.  What would cause this to happen?

Comment: Is there any error when you build your project?

Comment: @Mark No there is not.  File is updated on disk, IIS projects have been deleted, the old value is STILL being used.  wtf

Comment: Are you using the right web.config?  There's one in the root, and another in the views folder.  Wouldn't be the first time someone missed that...

Comment: What do you mean "connection string used, IIS applications are deleted"?

Comment: @PhillipXT Yes I am 100% sure.  There are no other instances of this cx string.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I have reset IIS.

Comment: No transforms are being used, no hidden files, I've checked the file on disk.  AH!

Comment: It looks like you found the BKM - sometimes VS tries to be clever and not update the .config file - this can be tied to the compile flavor (Release/Debug/etc) - and you can ultimately end up in an undetectable error state. Clean + Rebuild is the safest way to get around it each time you update a Connection String.

Comment: @Thumper I cleaned/rebuilt countless times.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted bin/debug and it started working.  I still have no idea why the web.config was being cached despite multiple edits, IIS restarts, etc.  Super frustrating.